# For Console Application using VS2022, I can't choose the desired .NET Framework

Tags: visual-studio

I have a console application. VS2022 is not listing any .NET Frameworks except 6.0 although I have others installed on the machine.

When using a Windows Application (not console application), I get to select the framework I want such as 4.7.2 for example.

I tried to re-install 4.7.2, but the installer was clever and figured that I already have it.

Confusing aspects in the project configuration from within the solution:

1. When no OS is selected, the programmer gets no warnings.
2. When OS is selected to be Windows, Not all the available .NET frameworks appear.

My question is how to "make/force" VS2022 to allow me to select the desired framework?

Thanks.

Comment: Pick the correct project template when you start, it needs to have ".NET Framework" in its name.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you for your reply, you brought a good point. There are many Console application configurations that I was not aware of. Please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it.